# Can we restrict users from accessing Office 365 (on Azure) from certain IP Addresses?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, office365

We are accessing Office 365 Mailbox on Azure cloud from AWS VPC through OAUTH 2.0. How can we impose restriction to allow Office 365 is accessible from only IP Address range of AWS VPC?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "O365 mailbox on Azure"... but generally, Azure AD Conditional Access Policies might be a way to do that (more specifically the Location policy which can work on IP ranges) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-policy-location

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/location-condition#trusted-locations

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an office 365 Mailbox and want to restrict its access for specific IP address , you can achieve it by enabling a Conditional Access Policy based on IP address. You need an either Azure Active Directory P1 or P2 license. Check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-policy-location) to get details about blocking access via Location based.

You can also impose restriction on the external side if you federation for AUTH process.